# Performance problems with random number of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, random, attributes, associations

I have a model for addressee in my rails application. The addressees all have a first name, a last name and a few other boolean attributes. In addition, these addressees will now receive additional attributes.
Users can have many addressees and should be able to extend these addressee datasets for own needs (e.g. street, zip, city). Most users don't extend addressees, some would store several other datas, but I don't know which data a user need for the addressees. To avoid hundreds of fields for the street, zip, city, phone numbers or any other data, I think about a kind of key-value-store. The keys will saved in addressee_key_labels and the corresponding value for each addressee and addressee_key_labels in addressee_key_value.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addressee_key_labels, :dependent => :destroy
end

class AddresseeKeyLabel < ActiveRecord :: Base
    belongs_to: user
    has_many: addressee_key_values, :dependent => :destroy
end

class AddresseeKeyValue < ActiveRecord :: Base
    belongs_to: addressee
    belongs_to: addressee_key_label
end

class Addressee < ActiveRecord :: Base
    has_many: addressee_key_values, :dependent => :destroy

    after_create :create_additional_values

    def create_additional_values
        unless self.user.addressee_key_labels.empty?
            self.user.addressee_key_labels.each do |addressee_key_label|
                addressee_key_value = AddresseeKeyValue.new()
                addressee_key_value.addressee_key_label_id = addressee_key_label.id
                addressee_key_value.addressee_id = self.id
                if self.additional
                    if addressee_key_label.is_secure
                        addressee_key_value.sec_data = self.additional[addressee_key_label.xmlname.downcase]
                    else
                        addressee_key_value.data = self.additional[addressee_key_label.xmlname.downcase]
                    end
                end
                addressee_key_value.save!
            end
        end
    end
end
```

My tests with faker gem tend to be very slow for many new addressees and 10 additional fields for each addressee, because I have 11 inserts to the database (one for the addressee and 10 for the additional fields). When I creating 1000 or more addressees (function for import from xls-document is planned), the process takes some minutes because there are some validations on addressee.

What can I do to speed this up without loosing callback possibilities?

I think about storing the data to the addressee table in a json/xml or other format. Is this a propper solution to throw less queries to database?

Comment: it would be much better if you attach some code

Comment: Can you also add in the user model as well? Can you also please explain why are you are implementing a hash for addressees?

Comment: I have updated code and attach an extract of the after_create callback. This creates all values for the Addressee and fill it with the values from the form. The form adds the additional fields dynamically from the defined labels of the account. The AddresseeKeyLabel has also a flag for storing encrypted values. The secure data will encrypted with strongbox gem. This wasn't the boddleneck in my tests. I think about storing addressees in a mongodb/couchdb to avoid the hassle with the number of queries.